# Count em múltiplas tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

Tenho 3 tabelas

[image: Tab1]
[image: tab2]

[image]

Eu preciso de uma query que pegue nome da escola, quantidade de classes tipo A, qtde de classes tipo B, qtde de alunos que estão nas classes tipo A, e qtde de alunos que estão nas classes tipo B.

Igual este exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei fazer

```
Select E.NOME,
SUM(CASE WHEN C.TIPO = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as CLTELE5A8,
SUM(CASE WHEN C.TIPO = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as CLTELEMED,
```

mas não sei como vou fazer a contagem de alunos

Comment: É uma simplificação das tabelas originais.

Comment: Comei a fazer uma solução, estou muito garrado. Talvez vc consiga terminar: [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/286ef/7/0)

Comment: É `MySQL` mesmo ou SQL Server como nas suas outras perguntas?

Comment: SQL Server, coloquei mysql por que não achei que mudaria muito a sintax da solução

Answer (score 1):

A forma mais simples de implementar é através de *subselect*. Caso isso te dê algum problema de *performance*, pode tentar usar uma [tabela temporária](http://www.devmedia.com.br/tabelas-temporarias-no-sql-server/2610).

```
Select E.NOME,
    SUM(CASE WHEN C.TIPO = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as CLTELE5A8,
    SUM(CASE WHEN C.TIPO = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as CLTELEMED,
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ALUNOS AA JOIN CLASSES CC ON CC.COD_CLASSE = AA.CODCLASSE WHERE CC.TIPO = 'A') as 'QTD_ALUNOS_A',
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ALUNOS AA JOIN CLASSES CC ON CC.COD_CLASSE = AA.CODCLASSE WHERE CC.TIPO = 'A') as 'QTD_ALUNOS_B'
```